# How to retrieve the data from a Jade form - Node.js

Tags: node.js, forms, web, pug

I have a Jade web page with a form in it. I would like to retrieve the data collected with this form using Node.js.

Here is my Jade code:

```
doctype html 
html
  head 
    title= userCreation 
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body 
    form(name="userCreationForm", method="POST", action="/userCreation")
        input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="PUT")
        p Name 
          input(type="text", name="name")
        p Email 
          input(type="email", name="email")
        p Age 
          input(type="number", name="age")
        p 
          input(type="submit")
```

and here is my Node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var user_dao = require('sport-track-db').user_dao;
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('user_creation');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("ah");
    console.log(req.body);
});
module.exports = router;
```

When I submit the form, "ah" is printed in my terminal, followed by "undefined".
Thanks in advance